# Sentence using 是……的 vs sentence using 很

Tags: grammar, difference

This might seem a duplicate question, since beginers have a lot of doubt about not using 是 instead of 很 as in 我很好, but there's nothing related to what I'm asking here. At least I haven't found anything.

What does a native speaker think about the difference between a sentence using 是...的 and the same one using 很? For example:

这本书**是**新**的**。
这本书**很**新。

商店的衣服**是**贵**的**。
商店的衣服**很**贵。

Thank you.

Comment: 这本书是新的。=> This book is new. 这本书很新。=> This book is very new.

Comment: You can also say : 这本书新。这本书是很新的。商店的衣服贵。商店的衣服是很贵的。So this should not be 是..的 vs 很。

Answer (score 6):

是…的 is used for emphasis. In this case, it is used for contrasting.

这本书是新的: This book is new (contrasting old).

这本书很新: This book is new (neutral or normal case).

Answer (score 0):

是……的 : just tell the status of the subject.

很: tell the feeling about the subject. more like **so...that...**

这本书是新的: this book is **new**. (emphasis for **new**. tell the status of book is new)

这本书很新: this book is **very** new.(emphasis for **very**, I feel this book so new <del>that I might want to do something about it</del>  ).

商店的衣服是贵的: the status of price of clothes in shop is expensive.

商店的衣服很贵: I feel the clothes in shop is so expensive (that...).

Answer (score 0):

这本书是新的（书） : this book is new (book) -- adjective+(noun)

这本书很新 : this book is new -- descriptive